# Multi-currency CSA discounting curve construction

Tags: derivatives, pricing

I have a number of eur/usd and gbp/usd MtM Basis swaps that are collaterized in USD. For the non-usd legs I'm constructing the muti-ccy csa discounting curve. Im using forwards for the short end of the curve and cross-currency basis swaps further out on the curve. Question is, should i be using constant notional cross currency swaps or MtM Basis swaps for this. MtM basis swaps are more liquid, so think they would be better, but not certain.The choice has a significant impact on my IR delta.

Comment: You should use MtM xccy which are more liquid, just make sure to use the appropriate pricers when bootstrapping.

Comment: Thanks Antoine. Would you be able to expand on what you mean by the "appropriate pricers"

Comment: Pricers that take into account the MtM reset. See https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1440633 for the full formulas that involve covariances for the various convexity adjustments. As a working approximation you can view the MtM xccy as a strip of forward start swaplets, each with reset leg notional equal to the fixed notional times the forward FX rate.